# Cannot interact with Window

Tags: winapi, opengl

I have created a simple OpenGL renderer that runs on Windows. I have no problems creating the window and setting the rendering context. The problem occurs after the window has been setup.

I cannot interact with the Window at all. If I mouse over anywhere on the Window, my cursor appears as a loading cursor. Here is the function I use to create the Window. Why is this happening?

```
bool BroGLWin::B_CreateWindow(int width, int height, int colorBits) {
if (!classRegistered) {
    WNDCLASS wc;

    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)wndproc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = sizeof(void*) + sizeof(int);
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    //wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hinstOpenGL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wc.lpszClassName = WINDOW_CLASS_NAME;

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) {
        // TODO: Add safe error here
        // unable to register class
    }
    classRegistered = true;
}

// create HWND
if (!hWnd) {
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
        WINDOW_CLASS_NAME,
        "BroGL",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        0,
        0,
        width,
        height,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hinstOpenGL,
        this
        );

    if (!hWnd) {
        // error creating the window
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
}

if (!(hDC = GetDC(hWnd))) {
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    hWnd = NULL;
    return false;
}

// Create OpenGL Context
if (!MakeContext()) {
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    hWnd = NULL;

    return false;
}

SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
SetFocus(hWnd);

return true;
}
```

Let me know if any more information is required.

EDIT: Here is the message loop.

```
LONG WINAPI BroGLWin::MainWndProc(HWND n_hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      break;
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
      LPCREATESTRUCT cs = reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam);
      void * lpCreateParam = cs->lpCreateParams;
      BroGLWin *win = reinterpret_cast<BroGLWin *>(lpCreateParam);
      assert(win == this);
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT 2: I have resolved my issue by properly implementing the message loop. The added code allowed the new messages to be read properly. Thanks to those who answered and left constructive comments. I also found the following website to be very helpful in this instance: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html

This is the code that I added to my `WinMain` function in `main.cpp`

```
// pump the message loop
while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE)) {
    if (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) < 0) {
        // Some error checking
    }
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Comment: Where is your Windows message loop?

Comment: Sorry about that. I assume that is why I am being penalized (downvoted)? Forgive my ignorance, I am rather new and did not know what to include. I will think twice before asking a question next time. I will add the message loop as soon as I can.

Comment: When in doubt post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @genpfault Thanks, that is good advice. I wish I would've considered that before hand. I made the mistake of assuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour that you report is symptomatic of an application that fails to respond to messages. It therefore seems most likely that you simply failed to implement a message loop, or implemented a broken message loop.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a missing or wrongly implemented message loop. Note that for the cursor image to be updated when the pointer enters the window you either have to call `SetCursor` in response to a mouse enter or mouse move event in your window, or have the cursor being set in the window class and fall through to calling `DefWindowProc` if you don't process those messages yourself. It's BTW always a good idea to pass *all* messages to 'DefWindowProc` and exclude only those, which you process yourself **and** don't want to be interpreted by the default Windows behavior as well.